# Swift Timer.scheduledTimer() doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I have two views in my swift app. I am performing a segue as below.

ViewController.swift -----------------> GameViewController.swift

When loading the GameViewController an value array also passed to GameViewController.swift from ViewController.swift

A timer should be initialized in GameViewController.swift

I tried to initialize a timer and call a method through it, but it doesn't work.

Followings are my code snippets.

ViewController.swift

```
func signIn(difficultyLvl:String){
    let username = usernameTxt.text
    let password = passwordTxt.text

    let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.106/speed/scoreBoardController.php?username="+username!+"&password="+password!+"&action=SIGNIN")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) {(data, response, error) in
        let isPassed = String(data: data!, encoding:.utf8)?.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)

        var gameViewControllerParams = [Int: [String: String]]()
        gameViewControllerParams[0] = ["userId" : isPassed!]
        gameViewControllerParams[1] = ["difficultyLvl" : difficultyLvl]

        if(isPassed != "null"){
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoGame", sender: gameViewControllerParams)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

GameViewController.swift

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    var gameViewControllerParams = [Int: [String: String]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target:self, selector: #selector(self.setCalculationLs), userInfo:nil,repeats: true)
    }

    func setCalculationLs(){
        print("Timing")
    }

}
```

Comment: I feel it is a problem with setting the target object in timer. Any suggetions. Thanks

Comment: You aren't sending the array to `GameViewController`, do that in `prepare(for:sender:)`.  the `sender` parameter should be `self`

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Is GameViewController loaded? Is viewDidLoad() called? How is the array passing related to the timer problem? – Generally, you timer code should work.

Comment: Also, make sure that the `performSegue` is being called from the main queue. Stuff that triggers UI changes always must happen from main thread. And, coincidentally, if you try to create timer on background thread, it won't work (unless you create run loop, which you definitely don't want to do here).

Comment: @paper1111 Actually prepare(for:sender:) was there in my code. I missed to include in to my question. Can you please check it again.

Comment: How about changing the `sender` parameter of `performSeuge` to `self`?

Comment: @paper1111 I tried to change it as self, but xcode notify it as a syntax error

Comment: Personally, while I think the use of the dictionary as the `sender` is a really bad idea, I don't think it would be the root of the problem. The problem rests elsewhere (like calling `performSegue` from background queue, e.g. inside `URLSession` completion handler).

Comment: @Rob I can confirm it's getting to the line that schedules the timer. But can you please explain your point of "Also, make sure that the performSegue is being called from the main queue ...."

Comment: @Rob yes, I am calling the perform segue inside URLSession completion handler. I will add that part also to my question

Comment: The `self.` reference before `performSegue` made me suspicious that you might have been calling it from a closure that is running on a background queue. Temporarily add a line that says `dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))` to the `viewDidLoad` of the game view controller (or where you call `performSegue`), just to make sure.

Comment: @Rob I updated the code in question with URLSession completion handler part. Can you please check with that ?

Comment: Yep, as I suspected, that is the problem.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Timers don't work on background queues (without some sleight of hand involving creating run loops or manually scheduling it on an existing run loop). But you should never initiate any UI update from anything other than the main queue, anyway.

So, since you're calling `performSegue` from a `URLSession` completion closure (which runs on a background queue), it's actually running `viewDidLoad` from the background queue, too. Thus the attempt to schedule the timer is failing. To get around this, you have to manually dispatch the `performSegue` code to the main queue:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
    ...

    if isPassed != "null" {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "gotoGame", sender: ...)
        }
    }
}
```

If you're ever unsure whether some code is running on the main queue or not, refer to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsession/1411597-init). Or you can use a dispatch precondition:

```
dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(.main))
```

That way it will (in debug builds) stop the app if you've accidentally invoked the code from a background queue.

---

Unrelated to your current problem, but as an aside, to avoid a strong reference cycle between the timer and the view controller, you generally want to keep a reference to the timer so that you can `invalidate` it when the view disappears (e.g. create timer in `viewDidAppear` and remove it in `viewDidDisappear`). Otherwise you can end up retaining the `GameViewController` after it was dismissed, e.g.:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target:self, selector: #selector(setCalculationLs(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)

        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    @objc func setCalculationLs(_ timer: Timer) {
        print("Tick")
    }
}
```

Or in iOS 10 or later, you can use the block-based variant with `weak` reference to `self`, and `invalidate` in `deinit`:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
            self?.setCalculationLs()
        }
    }

    deinit {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }

    func setCalculationLs() {
        print("Tick")
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh! it worked. Thank you very much for your kind support. This will be very helpful for new swift learners like me. And also I will try to change my application logic not to initiating UI update from anything other than the main queue. Thanks again

Comment: Rob, do you prefer the [weak self] method or viewDidLoad/viewDidDisappear method? Thanks.

Comment: I prefer the `[weak self]` pattern, but sometimes you have to use the old API because you're supporting old iOS versions. And if you are stuck with that old API, technically, while my example was `viewDidLoad`/`viewDidDisappear`, I'd probably suggest `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` (because those will always be balanced, whereas `viewDidLoad` might not be balanced with `viewDidDisappear` calls, notably if you `present` another view controller modally). I only used `viewDidLoad` above because that's where the OP was creating his timer in the original question.

Comment: I love when Apple mentions on their documentation about Timer that they do not work on background queues... wait, they didn't.

Comment: "Timers don't work on background queues" Finally I've found you! Thanks)))

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.5**

I was having this issue as well while working in a segued view controller. Since segues are executed as a background thread to the main thread (main view controller), running timer within the segued view controller won't work.  So, that being known and also knowing timers don't work in background threads, I did some digging and found [this Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/runloop) gem.

I added the following line right after my scheduled timer. The timer now works beautifully.  It is just sending the timer to the main thread for execution.

```
myTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateWithTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
RunLoop.main.add(myTimer, forMode: .common)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not the answer for this particular question, but my timer wasn't firing because I was thinking of timeInterval in terms of milliseconds instead of seconds. So my timer never fired. (Or, it would have fired eventually, but long after I expected or needed it).